# How I can create unique_ptr with custom deleter for C pointer?

Tags: c++

Original C-style code

```
Environment* env = Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::Mode::DEFAULT);
Connection* conn = env->createConnection(db_user_name, db_password, db_conn_str);
...
env->terminateConnection(conn);
Environment::terminateEnvironment(env);
```

I try get C++ with RAII code like this

```
std::unique_ptr<Environment, decltype(&Environment::terminateEnvironment)>env (Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::Mode::DEFAULT), &Environment::terminateEnvironment);
std::unique_ptr<Connection, decltype(&Environment::terminateConnection))>con(env->createConnection(db_user_name, db_password, db_conn_str), &(env->terminateConnection));
```

It's work in first line, but I get error with second line. I newbie in smart pointers. How I can get unique_ptr for Connection pointer???

Comment: So.. the original C-style has a bunch of pointers-to-functions in the `Environment` structure? Because that the only way that code will possibly compile in C.

Comment: I personally prefer to create dedicated `Deleter` instead of function pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a non-static member function as deleter. Instead write a lambda capturing the required `env` pointer and pass that to the `std::unique_ptr`:

```
auto connectionDeleter = [env=env.get()](auto ptr){
    env->terminateConnection(ptr);
};
std::unique_ptr<Connection, decltype(connectionDeleter)> con(env->createConnection(db_user_name, db_password, db_conn_str), connectionDeleter);
```

Note that this will not prevent you from accidentally freeing `env` before open connections are closed. If you want to have that guarantee, you need to pass `env` on as `shared_ptr` to the deleter:

```
std::shared_ptr<Environment> env(Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::Mode::DEFAULT), &Environment::terminateEnvironment);

auto connectionDeleter = [env](auto ptr){
    env->terminateConnection(ptr);
};

std::unique_ptr<Connection, decltype(connectionDeleter)> con(env->createConnection(db_user_name, db_password, db_conn_str), connectionDeleter);
```

Comment: This example return error "term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments". For first and second.

Comment: @NaydachiKamikadze Which line?

Comment: Error C2064 term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments  MSVC\14.24.28314\include\memory 1873

Comment: @NaydachiKamikadze Which line in the code in the answer does the error refer to? I cannot really test it myself, because you didn't provide a [repro] to test against.

Comment: line 1873 It's not my code, it's not build project with compiler error from Memory file. It's destructor for ~unique_ptr()

Comment: ~unique_ptr() noexcept {
        if (_Mypair._Myval2) {
            _Mypair._Get_first()(_Mypair._Myval2);
        }
    }

_Mypair._Get_first() and continue

Comment: @NaydachiKamikadze Which of the unique_ptr's? My first example, the second, or the one in your question? There is information in the output tab showing where the problem originates in the user code.

Comment: Thanks it's my mistake, I try run this

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's work. But I think that I not used more one connection :))

Comment: How I can declare my unique_ptr??? std::unique_ptr<Connection, std::function<void()>> ptr = std::unique_ptr<Connection, decltype(connectionDeleter)>(env->createConnection(db_user_name, db_password, db_conn_str), connectionDeleter); Not work

Comment: @NaydachiKamikadze The type is `std::unique_ptr<Connection, decltype(connectionDeleter)>`, not `std::unique_ptr<Connection, std::function<void()>>`. You do not need to repeat the type twice. `auto ptr = std::unique_ptr<Connection, decltype(connectionDeleter)>(env->createConnection(...), connectionDeleter);` or the form in my answer are both fine. If you want to specify the type somewhere else, then you should write a full functor object that can be named everywhere instead of using a lambda, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/what-are-c-functors-and-their-uses

Comment: Or you can make the type `std::unique_ptr<Connection, std::function<void(Connection*)>`.